# From Fermi-Dirac to Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I have a little question I can't seem to find the answer to. It is as follows:

When does [Fermi-Dirac statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics) reduce to [Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_statistics)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fermi-Dirac distribution

$$
f = \frac{1}{1+e^{(E-\mu)/kT}}
$$

where, $E$ is the energy, $\mu$ is the chemical potential and $kT$ is Boltzmann's constant times temperature reduces to the Boltzmann distribution

if $E \gg \mu$ then $e^{(E-\mu)/kT} \gg 1$ and so you can write
$$
f \approx e^{-(E-\mu)/kT}.
$$

Comment: The statement $E\gg\mu$ does not make much sense. Physically it is the value of $T$ that matters.

Comment: From Atkins, Physical Chemistry, p. 800: "For energies well above $\mu$, the 1 in the denominator can be neglected...".

Comment: Well, by $E\gg \mu$, TMOTTM clearly meant $E-\mu\gg kT$.