# About the Fermi-Dirac distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, mathematics

In order for a function $f$ to be a probability density, it must satisfy $$\int f dx=1,$$ where $x$ spans the domain of the random variable. If we take the Fermi-Dirac distribution $$\tag{1}f(E)=\frac{1}{e^{(E-E_F)/kT}+1}$$  at $T=0$, we find a step function like this

[image]

which is described by $$
f(E) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1 & \quad E < E_F \\
            0 & \quad E > E_F
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
So we clearly have $\int f(E)dE= E_F\neq 1$. So why is $(1)$ called a distribution?

Comment: Strictly speking, Fermi-Dirac is mean occupation number $\langle n \rangle$.. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics#Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_distribution

Comment: Since f(E) is unitless, having the integral be equal to an energy is problematic...

Comment: @JonCuster The units are OK because of.$dE$ contribution.

Comment: @Alexander - sigh, coffee stopped working. More to the point, that integral determines where $E_{f}$ actually is in the band structure.

Comment: Closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/275126/226902

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f(E)$ is not a probability density function: it gives the *probability* that a state with energy $E$ is occupied (notice that it is a dimensionless quantity). As such, it does not need to integrate to $1$, and it doesn't.

Comment: If each energy state has a probability of occupation (for $T > 0$), does this mean that at some instance maybe all the higher energy states are occupied?